# JPA - field must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key

Tags: java, jpa, foreign-keys, mapping

In my project I have two classes: `School` and `Teacher`. One school can have many teachers assigned. This is my code so far:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "schools", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
            "name"
    }})
public class School {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

...

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "teachers",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "school_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id"))
private Set<Teacher> teachersList = new HashSet<>();
```

And the other class looks as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teachers", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
            "id"
    })
})
public class Teacher {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

...
```

Now, when I try to build this project, I'm getting error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK4hetjkgnpo354f7uwax5aewc0:teachers
 [teacher_id])) must have same number of columns as the
referenced primary key (teachers [school_id,teacher_id])
```

and I'm lost here. What exactly am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Does the `teachers`-table have a column `school_id`? If so: does the `Teacher`-class have a corresponding `School`-field that is mapped as `@ManyToOne`?

Comment: Hm, teachers does not have schoold_id. Also, Teacher class does not have any corresponding School-field yet. How can I declare all of those missing data? Thanks so much for help!

Answer (score 0):

@JoinTable is used for ManyToMany relationships, you have to use @JoinColumn in your **Many** Entity side (Teachers)

Try this:

```
public class Teacher{
//...

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="fk_school_id") // this is your foreign key in your Teacher table of your DB
private School school;

}
```

But if you also want to retrieve the list of Teachers of every School you have to put this in your **One** Entity (School):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="school")
private List<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList();
```